# How to autoscale y-axis for bargraph in matplotlib?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

[image]

I need to autoscale the y-axis on my bargraph in matplotlib in order to display the small differences in values. The reason why it needs to be autoscaled instead of having a fixed limit is because the values will change depending on what the user inputs. I've tried `yscale` `log`, but that doesn't work for negative values. I've tried `symlog`, but the graph stays the same. This is my current code:

```py
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
y = range(700, 710, 1)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Plots are automatically scaled for the full range of the data provided to the API.
- For a bar plot, the best option to display the differences in the values of the bars, is probably to set the `ylim` for vertical bars or `xlim` for horizontal bars.

## negative data

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
y = range(-700, -750, -5)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 5))
ax.bar(x, y)
plt.ylim(min(y), max(y))
```

[image]

## positive data

```py
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
y = range(700, 750, 5)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 5))
ax.bar(x, y)
plt.ylim(min(y), max(y))
```

[image]

## mixed data

- If the data has a wide range of positive and negative values, there's probably not a good option, as you've noted `symlog` doesn't help the issue.

  - The best option may be to plot the positive and negative data separately.
- Creating a mask does't work with a list, so convert the lists to numpy arrays.

```py
import numpy as np

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
y = [700, -700, 710, -710, 720, -720, 730, -730, 740, -740]

x = np.array(x)
y = np.array(y)

mask = y >= 0  # positive mask

pos_y = y[mask]  # get the positive values
neg_y = y[~mask]  # get the negative values; ~ is not

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(7, 5))
ax1.bar(x[mask], pos_y)  # also mask x to plot the bar at the correct x-tick
ax1.set_title('Positive Values')
ax1.set_ylim(min(pos_y), max(pos_y))
ax1.set_xticks(range(0, 12))  # buffer the number of x-ticks, so the x-ticks of the two plots align.

ax2.bar(x[~mask], neg_y)
ax2.set_title('Negative Values')
ax2.set_ylim(min(neg_y), max(neg_y))
ax2.set_xticks(range(0, 12))

plt.tight_layout()  # better spacing between the two plots
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. Also I didn't have to do your 3rd solution for outputs that were both negative and positive.